# C++ STL: Trouble with iterators

Tags: c++, syntax, type-safety

I'm having a beginner problem:

```
bool _isPalindrome(const string& str)
{
    return _isPalindrome(str.begin(), str.end()); // won't compile
}

bool _isPalindrome(string::iterator begin, string::iterator end)
{
    return begin == end || *begin == *end && _isPalindrome(++begin, --end);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why doesn't `str.begin()` get type checked to be a `string::iterator`?

**Update:** Better version:

```
bool BrittlePalindrome::_isPalindrome(string::const_iterator begin, string::const_iterator end)
{
    return begin >= end || *begin == *(end - 1) && _isPalindrome(++begin, --end);
}
```

Comment: `s/string::iterator/string:const_iterator/`

Comment: Besides what you are asking about (types) there is a bug in the implementation. Consider a string with an odd number of characters.

Comment: Also, avoid using names beginning with underscore `_` in general. The concrete rules of what should be avoided are: any identifier beginning with double underscore (`__`) or beginning with a single underscore and a capital letter (`_X`) or beginning with a single underscore and a lower case letter in the global namespace (`_x`) are reserved for the implementation (compiler+standard libraries)

Comment: Doesn't `str.end()` point _past_ the last element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you have a declaration of the second function before the first function, the main issue is that you are passing the strings by `const` reference.

This means that the only overloads of `begin()` and `end()` that you have access to are the const versions which return `std::string::const_iterator` and not `std::string::iterator`.

The convention for iterators is that the end iterator points one beyond the end of a range and is not dereferencable - certainly if you pass `str.end()` as the `end` parameter. This means that `*begin == *end` is not valid, you need to decrement end once first. You are also going to have an issue with ranges with odd numbers of elements. By doing `++begin` and `--end` with no further checking your iterators may cross over in the recursion rather than triggering the `begin == end` condition.

Also note that for maximum portability, global identifiers shouldn't start with an underscore.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Actually these are class methods, but I took out the `ClassName::` to simplify the example. Is it still bad that the names start with `_`?

Comment: @Rosarch: So long as the second character isn't an upper-case letter and the identifier doesn't contain a double underscore then you are technically OK. Often, whether a function is a member function or not is important so you should avoid hiding this information from your question.

Answer (score 5):

`str.begin()` is non-const, while the argument `str` **is** const.

You can either change the iterator-accepting method to accept `const_iterator`s, or you can change the string-accepting method to accept a non-const `string`.

Or you could cast away `str`'s const-ness, but that would be a patent Bad Idea <sup>TM</sup>.

<sub>(I would also parenthesize your return statement on the iterator-accepting method to make your intent more clear, but that's neither here nor there.)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

As previously mentioned your iterators need to be constant iterators, but there's something else wrong with your algorithm. It works fine if you have a string of odd length, but do you see what happens when your string is even length? Consider the palindrome:

aa

Your algorithm will pass in an iterator pointing to the front and to the end. All's good, then it will go to the next level, and all will still be good, but it won't end. Because your first condition will never be true. You need to check not only if begin==end but if begin+1==end or begin==end-1 if you prefer. Otherwise you're iterators are going to be upset.

Answer (score 1):

What error are you getting?

Have you tried this?

bool _isPalindrome(string::const_iterator begin, string::const_iterator end)

Answer (score 1):

1. replace `iterator` by `const_iterator`
2. swap function definitions
3. decrement `end`

Code:

```
bool isPalindrome(string::const_iterator begin, string::const_iterator end)
{
  return (begin == end || begin == --end || 
          *begin == *end && isPalindrome(++begin, end));
}

bool isPalindrome(const string& str)
{
    return isPalindrome(str.begin(), str.end());
}
```

Comment: Your code isn't right, it will return true for any two character string.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared the second function before calling it in the first function. The compiler can't find it and thus tries to convert str.begin() (string::iterator) into a const string &. You can move the first function behind the second function.